# How to convert the .der file to .pub?

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, aes, openssh

Late I convert the .pub file to .der file through

```
ssh-keygen -f ran.pub -e -m PKCS8 | openssl pkey -pubin -outform DER -out pub.der
```

and current I want to convert .pub file to .der 
But here when I try .der file to .pem or other .pub it can't convert
I tried this

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in pub.der -out certificate.pem
```

But it will getting error

```
unable to load certificate
4601439852:error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.200.4/libressl-2.6/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:683:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution

```
openssl rsa -in pub.der -pubout -out pub.pem
```